# Understanding the error caused by ng-pattern

Tags: angularjs, design-patterns

I'm using ng-pattern in order to get the correct format of the user phone number. But when I tried to run the app Im getting an error stating `Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 0-0 [^] in expression [^(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}-)\d{3}-\d{4}$].`I can't figure out what is the reason. Please I need help in this.

```
 <input type="tel" name="phoneno" maxlength=10  ng-model="phone.number" ng-pattern="^(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}-)\d{3}-\d{4}$" required/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the "//" regex delimiters which is probably causing this issue.

```
 <input ... ng-pattern="/^(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}-)\d{3}-\d{4}$/" required/>
```